# changing a hash value from string to array

Tags: perl

data.txt

```
 Name:xyz
 ID:1
 Value: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 ID:2 
 Value: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1..
 ID:3
 Value: 90 89 88....
 Name:abc
 ID:11
 value:...
```

Intial file.txt

```
## Header 
..
data
data
data
..
```

Final expected file.txt

```
## Header xyz_1,xyz_2,xyz_3,abc_11,...
..
data 1 9 90
data 2 8 89
data 3 7 88
data 4 6 
..
```

Current output file.txt

```
## Header xyz_1,xyz_2,xyz_3,abc_11,...
...
data, 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ..,9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 ..,90 89 88
data
data
...
```

Code

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use diagnostics;
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my @name_id;
my %test;

#local $/ = '';

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die "failed: $!";
my %var;
while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  if (m/^([A-Z:]+):\s*(.*)/) {
    $var{$1} = $2;
    if (exists($var{Name}) && exists($var{ID}) && exists($var{value}) && $1 eq 'value') {
      my $var_name = "$var{Name}_$var{ID}";
      push @name_id, $var_name;
      $test{$var_name} = $var{value};
    }
  }
}

#   print join "\n\t", @test{@name_id};
my $match = "## Header";
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die "failed : $!";
for my $line (@lines) {
  if ($line =~ /^($match.*)/) {
    $line = $1 . "," . join ',', @name_id;
  }
}
untie @lines;

my $match = "data";
tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die "failed : $!";
my $i = 0;
for my $line (@lines) {
  if ($line =~ /^($match.*)/) {
    $line = $1 . "," . join(',', map { $test{$_}->[$i] } @name_id);
    $i++;
  }
}
untie @lines;
```

Have a problem with this line  `$line = $1 . "," . join (',', map { $test{$_}->[$i]} @name_id);` it throws the error

> Can't use string ("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .."...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at test.pl line 46,  line 80. at test.pl line 46

I think the hash(`%test`) value I had is a string and I can't split it as an array. Please let me know how to convert it to an array. I tried doing `$test{$var_name} = [qw($var{value})];` it didnt work.

Comment: Why would you mix `$i` and `$1` in the same code together?  Why :(.  Please rename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in this refactoring of your code that seems to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die "failed: $!";

my @name_id;
my %test;
my %var;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  if (my ($key, $val) = /^(\w+):\s*(.*)/) {
    $var{$key} = $val;
    if ($key eq 'value') {
      my $var_name = "$var{Name}_$var{ID}";
      push @name_id, $var_name;
      $test{$var_name} = [ split ' ', $var{value} ];
    }
  }
}

tie my @lines, 'Tie::File', 'file.txt' or die "failed : $!";
my $count = 0;
for my $line (@lines) {
  if ($line =~ /^## Header/) {
    $line .= ' ' . join ',', @name_id;
  }
  elsif ($line =~ /^data/) {
    $line .= ' ' . join ' ', map { $test{$_}[$count] // '' } @name_id;
    $count++;
  }
}
untie @lines;
```

**output** (`file.txt`)

```
## Header xyz_1,xyz_2 ,xyz_3
data 1 9 90
data 2 8 89
data 3 7 88
data 4 6
```

Answer (score 1):

This is surely not right:

```
$test{$_}->[$i]
```

Because `$test{$_}` can only contain a string of some sort.

If you have a string and want to split into an arrayref so the above works, do this:

```
$test{$var_name} = [split /\s+/, $var{value}];
```

I have no idea what the code is supposed to accomplish which means that it may run, but I can't tell if it does what it is meant to. The odd variable names (like `$test` and `$var_name` didn't help me to understand the purpose).

Comment: it worked. Thats what I need although it complains for ` $line = $1 . "," . join (',', map { $test{$_}->[$i]} @name_id);` Use of uninitialized value in join or string at test4.pl line 47, <$fh> line
        141 (#1)

Comment: Maybe you can reopen a new question with the new code. I still think you should clean up the variable names, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure I followed your code, but I thought I'd post how to transpose the numbers (unless your code already does that  :-)  ).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my (%data, $name);
while (<DATA>) {
    if (/^Name:(.+)/) {
        $name = $1  
    }
    elsif (/^Value/) {
        # transpose
        my $r = 0;
        push @{ $data{$name}[$r++] }, $_ for /\d+/g;
    }   
}

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%data;

__DATA__
Name:xyz
ID:1
Value: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
ID:2 
Value: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
ID:3
Value: 90 89 88 87 86 85 84 83 82
Name:abc
ID:11
```

The dumped results are:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'xyz' => [
                     [
                       '1',
                       '9',
                       '90'
                     ],
                     [
                       '2',
                       '8',
                       '89'
                     ],
                     [
                       '3',
                       '7',
                       '88'
                     ],
                     [
                       '4',
                       '6',
                       '87'
                     ],
                     [
                       '5',
                       '5',
                       '86'
                     ],
                     [
                       '6',
                       '4',
                       '85'
                     ],
                     [
                       '7',
                       '3',
                       '84'
                     ],
                     [
                       '8',
                       '2',
                       '83'
                     ],
                     [
                       '9',
                       '1',
                       '82'
                     ]
                   ]
        };
```